# How to Enable HTTP to HTTPS (SSL Certification) among all miscro services in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, ssl-certificate, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I am Currently working in micro services project in spring boot. In this I have more than 10 services. I am using Eureka server, and all other micro services are registered with this Eureka server. When I am changing Eureka server from http to https(SSL certificate using keystore) Other instances are not get registered with eureka server.

I have changed all micro services from http to https, Still i am getting same problem.

I am configured all the micro services with the same keystore file. Is this is problem?

Can anyone please help, which configuration is missing?

My application.yml :

```
server:
  ssl:  
    key-alias: selfsigned
    key-password: password
    key-store: classpath:keystore.jks
    key-store-provider: SUN
    key-store-type: JKS
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need the service to service calls to be https? And if so does it need to be at the Spring boot layer? Often times it's much easier to SSL terminate at the load balancer and allow everything behind the load balancer to be http only.

Comment: No specific reason.. my requirement is like this. you said, load balancer allow everything to be http only, can you have any documentation for this?

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: I'm not getting any exceptions. Micro services not registered with eureka server, If i enabled SSL.

Comment: @BillO'Neil some more information to help with your point would be helpful - I am trying to do exactly what you suggest but not sure where to start